# Choosing password and storing password and private key

Tags: security, passwords, ssh-keys

In my company we're developing a product powered by an ARM processor. We are using Buildroot to make a Linux system for it.

For debugging/maintenaince purposes, SSH access will be enabled using ethernet and the device will have an UART for Serial TTY. The product will be sold to companies, and likely only workers will have physical access to the device.

I would like to know what strategy must we follow regarding user password and private key storage:

- Password: what user password must we choose? Choosing one password for all doesn't seem a very good idea. If someone find out this password, he will have access to all our devices, and we can't update them since they're offline. Do we even need to choose a password? Is there any other solution that is secure and doesn't rely on passwords? Something similar to SSH keys, maybe...
- SSH private key: I'm considering to generate a key pair and add the public key in authorized_keys file of all devices. This way, any member of our company that have to do maintenaince can import the private key to his computer and directly have access to all devices. But how we could store this private key to keep it reasonable secure (and don't loosing it)?

Security is not critical in this device, since it is not likely to be an interesting objective to hack, its function is not important at all, it is offline and physical access to it will be reasonably restricted. Knowing this, I would like to have answers to points above so we have reasonable security without overcomplicating everything.

Some things I have thought about SSH keys:

- Writting it in a paper and keep it in our office: I don't like this very much because I don't trust it not being lost, destroyed...
- Saving it in our private Git repository in Bitbucket: I don't dislike this one very much because the same people that have access to repository should be allowed to have the private key, but I don't know how much I must trust in a cloud service for this

I remember that security requirements are not high in this case, but still want to have reasonably good practices.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not set the same password for all devices, or use the same ssh key. Having the ssh key for your company in `authorized_keys` would effectively be a vendor backdoor. Don't do that. It's also a huge reputational risk for your company, if that key ever gets compromised, your product is probably out of business.

Depending on the actual usecase of your devices, a few relatively secure options you can choose from:

- Upon setting up the device by (or at least *at*) the customer, a new keypair or password could be generated or entered. This secret would then remain with the customer and your company would eliminate the huge risk of storing a master secret for all devices.
- You can pre-generate a random password for each device, set it as the password, print it on a piece of paper and stick it on the device. Your company then forgets about that password, and the client should of course be able to change it. This way, there is no master secret for all devices, and an attacker needs physical access to read the password. Note that while something like the mac address sounds like a good candidate for the password, it is not, because it is far too easy to guess. It should be a real random password with sufficient entropy. Also note that this requires that only authorized people have physical access to the device - that's usually the case, but you have not specified what kind of device this is.

Both of these require a one-time setup phase for the device at the customer though.

Comment: I understand from the point of view of security, but this doesn't solve the problem: we need to access the devices for debugging/maintentaince.The client is not going to never use that password and key, they don't need it and probably they don't want it, and probably they will not be careful storing it. Also, the same client is going to buy many devices, so it is not useful for them nor for us to make them to save hundreds of passwords and keys, and keeping track of which device correspond to each password and key.

Comment: @naggety Well, it's all about risk. If your company loses a master key, your company is liable. If your customer loses their own key, you are ok. Whenever you need maintenance access, they can provide you with the password, which they are supposed to change afterwards. If you want to take a much higher risk, you can also store these secrets for them, but consequences are quite far reaching. For example what if a customer infrastructure is hacked through your device, damage is in the million dollars, and it turns out the password for the device was stolen from your company?

Comment: So I think I totally understand what you are after, but the potential risk sounds too big and unnecessary to take.